# How to convert an image to a compressed string representation equivalent to one copied to clipboard by `CopyToClipboard[image]`?

Tags: syntax, image, expression-manipulation, boxes, clipboard

In my recent question I asked [How to embed an image into a string?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27111/how-to-embed-an-image-into-a-string)
The suggested solution was

```
(* In[1]:= *) image = Import["https://wolfram.com/favicon.ico", "Image"];
(* In[2]:= *) str = ToString[image, StandardForm];
```

If I execute

```
(* In[3]:= *) CopyToClipboard[str];
```

and then paste it into a plain text editor (e.g. *notepad* on *Windows*) than I get a very long and verbose string:

```
\!\(\*GraphicsBox[TagBox[RasterBox[RawArray["Byte", List[List[List[0, 0, 0, 0], (* ... *) List[0, 0, 0, 0]]]], List[List[0, 16], List[16, 0]], List[0, 255], Rule[ColorFunction, RGBColor]], BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", Rule[ColorSpace, "RGB"], Rule[Interleaving, True]], Rule[Selectable, False]], Rule[BaseStyle, "ImageGraphics"], Rule[ImageSizeRaw, List[16, 16]], Rule[PlotRange, List[List[0, 16], List[0, 16]]]]\)
```

But if I copy the image to the clipboard directly

```
(* In[4]:= *) CopyToClipboard[image];
```

and then paste it into a plain text editor than I get a compressed representation:

```
\!\(\*
GraphicsBox[
TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["
1:eJyNUgss1HEc/+9CKBIyz928OodzCOdxcU95njh5tIQbpvUgDrFKWtIDPaZk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"], {{0, 16}, {16, 0}}, {0, 255},
ColorFunction->RGBColor],
BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True],
Selectable->False],
BaseStyle->"ImageGraphics",
ImageSizeRaw->{16, 16},
PlotRange->{{0, 16}, {0, 16}}]\)
```

Both the long and compressed strings, if being pasted back to a *Mathematica* notebook, are automatically represented as the original image:

```
(* In[5]:= *)
```

I am interested in

> *Question 1*: How to get the compressed string programmatically, without using the clipboard?

The content of `CompressedData["..."]` looks like a result of the [`Compress`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compress.html) function, and indeed it could be checked that

```
(* In[6]:= *) ToBoxes[image][[1, 1, 1]] === 
 Uncompress["
  1:eJyNUgss1HEc/+9CKBIyz928OodzCOdxcU95njh5tIQbpvUgDrFKWtIDPaZk
  tLTmIiJbWR6pbLVSlNSI0S0j4bS8tiZ9Oi1NFvluv99+n+++n31/3+/nYyxK
  CIojEQSRrCy/gqLT2ElJ0elCBTngpItjRWvkD43fZz75v3ibne/1+uIF0ipK
  iVviDPd37ADrBdyRdYz8zZYz9yozS3UhdyckeVPl+csq/+LnpR7hvqG4yUaZ
  /AP9gf6uMgqtdZwgoY3ilFbtEqJ5gxaa+Zizp7CuVKK03B+K1OwBkgl+MM1m
  RnjG6GQZo1tJD7V6HGkTwUMfK0Gw0gyZWvSJJ0r2GBP5Y6goBv054ai3scU5
  goEhgosB3zjHpZyykL2pD0nMqadkZ9yj2qOSYOKBiRcaOf4oZ3CRqspAsaEH
  oO8IaNFHe7lBZlLPMKMB7g7qPL+ktEStx0kgnTO1xEBwAHrpbIz7haNdKESN
  JwtnTeho5nOByG2YJXQBQgdf6VvRHbsv/c+uoyPM4eeK4TA/TIYJgIJTmC6/
  irbcFNzmuaEpKhgTp3fik54aBnU2fR7wFdAXz9DnI5S8NzLHc3MqZAejMFlx
  Ed8bqyAryseL7d6otnBAX7wQI+SNaN3mJVnglSYeXfuAubuhTnGzfEcaqNI3
  RWegN3pOijFYdAJIT4DU2Rk3FSwgUWOgS8UK/dpWaDicwZvnF0Ts55+nel/K
  0bU9U2VocP1ZgLu8Hw/tgTxI4/0wEcDEoKMDWmy24Jy6BY4Tlrgm16fOjj9V
  IT4kWqpFl4217EOoJx7RLdCqtwEfPe0AcTDAdsBLbTrynH3Tdhmz1TPN+I7F
  nCCXv3SMiF9fS1DQTKZBomMwUUNoYZpCwwzVAF8IVYwquqAlu0B5Oe8UBsb4
  FPPC48o8vDWvkC1Z9Spus8PrGLjLYf3ya6ey3VhHbnHESv5bHPVOYe0Ngkjf
  Bdxs6aFy/2Q+bbX8mpScjCpRovZKNT8BKotUng==
  "]
(* Out[6]= True *)
```

Unfortunately, `RawArray`, `CompressedData` and `` BoxForm`ImageTag `` are all undocumented. It looks like `RawArray` represents (probably, optimized) internal representation of a multi-dimensional array, and `CompressedData` is equivalent to `Uncompress` (e.g. unless being held, it automatically evaluates to the object represented by the compressed string) except that `CompressedData` can be successfully interpreted as part of an input of the form `\!\(\* ... \)`.

> *Question 2:* Did I get their meaning right? Can they be useful in any other context?

Assuming I did it right, the closest result I was able to obtain to what I need is given by

```
(* In[7]:= *) toCompressedString[image_Image] :=
  "\!\(\*" <> ToString[
    ToBoxes[image] /.
     array_RawArray :> 
      With[{compressed = Compress[array]}, 
       CompressedData[compressed] /; True],
    InputForm] <> "\)";
```

(`/; True` is the [Trott-Strzebonski trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/how-to-inject-an-evaluated-expression-into-a-held-expression/2680#2680) that I learned trying to write this code).

Is there a more strightforward way to get this string?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the internal expression of the cell containing the image, you'll find that it also uses the compressed form. However, the usual trick of `Cell@BoxData@ToBoxes...` doesn't seem to work here, as that only gives us the `RawArray` representation. This gives us a hint at a possible way of retrieving the compressed representation without having to build it up ourselves.

In the following implementation, we create a new document with the image, flip the cell to show its expression (as if you had chosen `Cell > Show Expression` from the menu bar), copy its contents and then discard the notebook.

```
ClearAll@getCompressedString
getCompressedString[img_] := Module[{nb = CreateDocument[img, Visible -> False], str},
    SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
    FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "ToggleShowExpression"];
    str = First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[NotebookSelection[nb], "InputText"]]];
    NotebookClose@nb;
    First@StringCases[str, x : ("GraphicsBox" ~~ __) :> StringDrop[x, -2]]
]
```

If you now call `getCompressedString` on your image, you should get the string you want, which you can then pad with `"\!\(\*"` and `"/)"` to get back the image.

Comment: It's an interesting approach, I voted it up. But I would not call it a "more straightforward" than the one given in the question. Probably, it has a much more significant overhead. And it fails with [`FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/FrontEndObject/notavail.html) message when there is no GUI Front End running (e.g. when executed from a console).